# Correct way to bind data with angular.extend in resolved promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to change my angular code from **this.vm** to **angular.extend** for get more clarity about private and public variables/methods when i use controller as syntax, but i can't get data binding from a resolved promise.

```
// public data to view

var resolvedData;
var otherVar;

angular.extend(this, {
  myVar: resolvedData,
  mySecondVar: otherVar
})

myFactoty.action().then(function(data){
  resolvedData = data;
})
```

here i don't have any data binding to my view, but when i try like this:

```
// public data to view

var resolvedData;
var otherVar;

angular.extend(this, {
  myVar: resolvedData,
  mySecondVar: otherVar
})

myFactoty.action().then(function(data){
  angular.extend(this, {
    myVar: data
  })
})
```

I got: Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined.

How can i get the data binding in a correct and good practices way?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *clarity* you are trying to acheive but you already have a context problem with `this` not being what you expect it to be inside the promise callback

```
// always store a reference to `this`
var vm= this;

myFactoty.action().then(function(data){
  //   this != vm because it's inside a function closure
  angular.extend(this, { // won't work
    myVar: data
  });
});
```

So to extend the controller use the stored reference inside any closures

```
myFactoty.action().then(function(data){
  angular.extend(vm, {
    myVar: data
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this solve my problem with **Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined.**, but its the only way to get the data binding?

Comment: no, angular is very good at picking up view changes without needing to do this. Not sure what specific binding problem you are encountering

Comment: the only way is using angular.extend every time that i want to bind data to my views?